# Error while declaring primitive in verilog

Tags: verilog

The following is the source code that I have written for a 2-to-1 mux using primitive:

```
primitive mux_2 (output out,
                input in1, in2, s);
table
  //in1 in2 s   : out
  ? ?   x   :   0;
  1 ?   0   :   1;
  0 ?   0   :   0;
  ? 0   1   :   0;
  ? 1   1   :   1;
endtable

endprimitive
```

However compiling the code gives me this error:

> Line 1: syntax error. I give up.

I have followed a book to write this code and I am not sure what the syntax error is. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.hdlworks.com/hdl_corner/verilog_ref/items/UserDefinedPrimitives.htm) specification your code should look something like this:

```
primitive mux_2 (out, in1, in2, s);
    output out;
    input in1, in2, s;
    table
    //in1 in2 s   :  out
      ?   ?   x   :   0;
      1   ?   0   :   1;
      0   ?   0   :   0;
      ?   0   1   :   0;
      ?   1   1   :   1;
    endtable
endprimitive
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my issue. However, I have read that ANSI style definitions are also valid and I just confirmed that it depends on the compiler used. I was initially using Icarus Verilog 0.9.7 when it threw an error. But when I changed compiler, my style of definition also worked

Comment: I was not aware of that either, thank you for letting me know :)

Comment: It is a bug in Icarus, even exists in v0.10.0 (Nov 23, 2014). Note that The ANSI header of `primitive mux_2 (output out, input in1, input in2, input s);` does work since v0.9.6 (possibly sooner).